# How to integrate SocketMobile with React Native application?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, socketscan, socketmobile

I have Android and iOS React Native app that requires user to scan barcodes. For now we use device's camera for scanning, but there is a requirement to use handheld scanner.

How do I integrate my application with SocketMobile scanner?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like SocketMobile has its own [SDK](https://www.socketmobile.com/developers/welcome) for mobile developers. Probably your problem will be solved via bluetooth communication between the scanner and the Android device, but read through the documentation on the website to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

There is no official Javascript support at the moment.

In order to use the SDK in a React Native app, you need to create your own Javascript bindings for the iOS or Android version of the SDK